# PHP's default tidy VS developer custom made tidy

Tags: php, oop, php-5.3, htmltidy

I know there is `tidy` php class by default already, what about if I want to create my own custom tidy class and I want to name that class as **tidy** too?

```
class tidy
{
    public function html()
    {
        return 'local';
    }
}

$tidy = new tidy();
echo $tidy->html();
```

error,

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class tidy in
>   C:\wamp\www\test\2012\php\dom_tidy_html_8.php on line 11

How can I not to conflict with PHP's default `tidy`?

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

I tested it with `namespace` and it works but I am not whether this is a good practice or not...? I haven't done anything with `namespace` before so I am not sure whether it is safe or not...

```
namespace tidy;

class tidy
{
    public function html()
    {
        return 'local';
    }
}

$tidy = new tidy();
echo $tidy->html();
```

Would it cause any problem if I want to use the PHP default `tidy` **occasionally**?

Comment: [Namespaces](http://php.net/namespaces)

Comment: Thanks but how to use namespace to archive that? I haven't tried anything with namespace yet...

Comment: @lauthiamkok Namespaces are designed to solve you issue, please read up on them here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php.

Comment: thanks, ilanco. I am now using namespace :-) thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build on top of tidy then just extend the tidy class and call is myTidy.

```
class myTidy extends tidy
{
    public function html()
    {
        return 'local';
    }
}

$tidy = new myTidy();
echo $tidy->html();
```

If you want to create your own implementation from scratch try to remove the tidy module and then create the tidy class.

If you are using PHP >= 5.3.0 you can also create your own tidy class in a Namespace :

```
namespace My\Tidy;

class tidy
{
    public function html()
    {
        return 'local';
    }
}

$tidy = new tidy();
echo $tidy->html();
```

Comment: thanks. it seems that give it a different name is the only option.

Comment: It seems I can make it with `namespace`. Please see my edit above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just name it something different:

```
class my_tidy
{
    public function html()
    {
        return 'local';
    }
}

$tidy = new my_tidy();
echo $tidy->html();
```

Comment: It seems I can make it with `namespace`. Please see my edit above.  Thanks.